# SlowCheetah "File to transform not found" when transforming json in wwwroot folder / ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, slowcheetah

I wanted to add an environment.json for my Angular SPA (non angular-cli) to be transformed on build/publish.
It works for the root directory but not if the json is inside the wwwroot folder, where I want the file to be served statically.
As soon as I add transforms to my json file, building/publishing fails with error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error MSB4018 The "SlowCheetah.TransformTask" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File to transform not found File
>   name:
>   **'D:\myproject\wwwroot\enviroment.json;D:\myproject\wwwroot\enviroment.json'**
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.JsonTransformer.Transform(String
>   source, String transform, String destination) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.TransformTask.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()  Axa.AxaHome.Backoffice.Client.UI.Web
>   C:...\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.slowcheetah\3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets    83

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, I now added the environment.json (with transforms) to the root of the project and another environment.json (without transforms) to the wwwroot folder (Build Action = Content). Then I added following build target to the project file:

```
  <Target Name="CopyTransformedFile" AfterTargets="ScApplyTransforms">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)\environment.json" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\wwwroot\environment.json" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)\environment.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\environment.json" ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
```

When debugging locally, or when deploying, the the transformed file will now be used.